# ESDoc: How to exclude a dir

Tags: javascript, regex, documentation, esdoc

I have 2 directories, one to keep to generate documentation and not the other one. They're:

- client-dev
- client

Directory `client-dev` is to be included in generating documentation. The other one, `client` should not be included.

My .esdoc.json file:

```
{
    ...
    "excludes": ["(node_modules|client)"]
    ...
}
```

Specifying `client` in the `excludes` option above will exclude `client-dev` too because it contains the word `client`. How to keep `client-dev` but exclude `client`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it out how, it's rather simple.

Adding a slash after `client` will exclude everything in it, and that doesn't spoil the selection of files in `client-dev`:

```
{
    ...
    "excludes": ["(.git|node_modules)","client/"]
    ...
}
```